# Next.js Unit Test with jest --coverage Error

Tags: jestjs, babeljs, next.js

I create web application using Next.js and making unit test using jest. I set up the project using the template from create-next-app with-jest (https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-jest). Everything work fine until I add styling using style-jsx. When I run `jest --coverage`, I got this error.

```
TypeError: Property body[1] of BlockStatement expected node to be of a type ["Statement"] but instead got "SequenceExpression"

  at validate (node_modules/@babel/types/lib/definitions/utils.js:128:13)
  at validator (node_modules/@babel/types/lib/definitions/utils.js:97:7)
  at Object.validate (node_modules/@babel/types/lib/definitions/utils.js:172:7)
  at validate (node_modules/@babel/types/lib/validators/validate.js:17:9)
  at builder (node_modules/@babel/types/lib/builders/builder.js:46:27)
  at Object.BlockStatement (node_modules/@babel/types/lib/builders/generated/index.js:260:31)
  at NodePath.replaceExpressionWithStatements (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/replacement.js:209:57)
  at NodePath.insertBefore (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/modification.js:49:17)
  at processTaggedTemplateExpression (node_modules/next/node_modules/styled-jsx/dist/babel-external.js:97:16)
  at node_modules/next/node_modules/styled-jsx/dist/babel-external.js:183:11
```

When I only run `jest` without coverage, the test passed.

I have read the same issue in here https://github.com/zeit/styled-jsx/issues/436. However, the issue is still open and no one find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you use the canary version of nextjs as of today the error will go away :)